# AzureDevops - extract test steps to powerbi with odata query

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I need to extract a table with test steps that correspond to each test case, from AzureDevops  to PowerBI.

I was able to retrieve a list of tables that I can extract with odata, but none of them contains test steps. I’m attaching the metadata request and an extract of its results. [extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhPhZ.jpg)

I’ve read that another possibility would be you to use an api query, but I’m not sure which one.

Does anyone know a possible solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the note in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-views-create?view=azure-devops#select-the-fields-to-appear-in-the-report),

> You can’t add fields with a data type of Plain Text (long text) or HTML (rich-text). These fields aren’t available from Analytics for the purposes of reporting.

And the type of the Steps field is Text (multiple lines), so they cannot be extract with odata.
[image]

You can try to use [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get the detail of the testcase which will contain the Steps detail. Please refer the screenshot:
[image]